# Where to find the terminal logs in Mysql

Tags: linux, mysql, logging, ubuntu-10.04

I connect to mysql client using the command

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

And I execute queries there. If I press the up arrow, i could see the history of almost all the queries there. Where will this query log be stored.

I found a log file under `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log` and I indeed see some logging happening there. But it has queries from other users as well. However, I only need queries executed by the specific user (`root` in this case). How to get it? Please help me.

Note: I need to debug some logs, so a solution to filter these logs with the existing setup would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

History for `root`  is stored in `/root/.mysql_history`.

Comment: For non-root users: `/home/nonrootusername/.mysql_history` . If you are using GUI and you don't see hidden files, firt try pressing `Ctrl + H` while in the folder, if that doesn't help, search the Internet :)